# openGL unattached texture refers to other texture

Tags: opengl, textures

If I've a shader that uses two textures, and one of them is not set for the first few draws (because I'm fetching it over the network), the program will use the second texture for the first one, instead of sampling from a default black.

For instance, if my fragment shader is:

```
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2; // this is a color filter

varying mediump vec2 v_textureCoordinate;

void main() {
  mediump vec3 rgb = texture2D(texture1, v_textureCoordinate);
  rgb.r = texture2D(texture2, vec2(rgb.r, 0.5).r);

  gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

and I use it after `texture2` is set and before `texture1` is set, sampling from `texture1` will sample from `texture2`, instead of from a default empty texture. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> instead of sampling from a default black

There is no such thing as an "black default texture". The `sampler` types do not reference textures in GLSL, but texture *units*. So either there is some complete texture bound to the (matching target of) that texture unit, or there isn't.

As Andon M. Coleman pointed out in the comments, there is conceptually no way to have no texture bound, since texture object 0 refers to a valid texture object in the GL, the default texture object. But that does not contain any image data initially, so it is just incomplete.

**UPDATE**

<s>When sampling from an incomplete texture, the return value of your sample operation will be just *undefined*.</s>

Actually, as Reto Koradi pointed out in a comment, sampling from an incomplete texture is well-defined in the GL. It will yield (0,0,0,1). However, when using `texelFetch` on an incomplete texture, the results will be undefined (unless the context was created with [robust buffer access behavior](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/robust_buffer_access_behavior.txt)).

But since you use `texture2D`, you would be safe here. However ,you aren't accessing an incomplete texture.
Uniforms are by default initialized to zero. As a result, both `texture1` and `texture2` will initially refer to texture unit `GL_TEXTURE0`. If you happen to use that unit for your first usage of `texture2`, then the `texture1` sampler will end up accessing the same texture.

Comment: I see, thanks. Any idea on how to create a black texture while real content is loading? I could not really find something.

Comment: Creating a dummy 1x1 texutre with just one black pixel shouldn't be very hard to do.

Comment: There's always something bound to a texture unit :P Even the name **0** is a valid texture with initially incomplete state (**0** is unique for each target, but that aside functions like a regular texture). The state of that texture will become corrupted over time in a lot of applications because many developers assume that binding **0** means texture commands have no effect :-\

Comment: Much of this is wrong. Sampling from an incomplete texture is guaranteed to give black. See for example section 3.9.2 of the OpenGL 3.3 spec.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: you are perfectly right. I did look the up in the spec before I wrote the answer. However, I ended up in the wrong place (in GL3.3 spec section 2.11.7), which covers texel fetches, not texture samplings... I'll update my answer.